# jQuery Remove LI from UL with a hyperlink in the LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a unordered list:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">First <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
  <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">Second <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
  <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">Third <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove the `<li>` from the `<ul>`. I have handled the click event of the class itemDelete where I try to do a remove but I assume its not working because I can't remove the `<li>` as a child is calling it?

```
$('.itemDelete').live("click", function() {
            var id = $(this).parent().get(0).id;


            $("#" + id).remove();

        });
```

What's the best approach?

Comment: Your IDs are invalid - IDs can't start with digits

Comment: @Jon your question is very very help me

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Assuming you're using a recent version of jQuery:

```
$('#sortable').on('click', '.itemDelete', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

`closest` is a little more dynamic than `parent` (although `parent` works here as well.) It gets the `li` that is closest to the current element, upwards in the structure.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the way you have it as of now, `id` is going to be undefined, because none of the li's have ids.

why not just do

```
$(this).parent().remove()
```

also, don't forget to return false.

Comment: i do have id's forgoto to paste them into the original post

Answer (score 6):

You don't have IDs on your `<li>`s

How about simply

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

What wound up working for me:
Prefix your id attributes with a string or underscore (as others have pointed out)

Since frameworks like jQuery Mobile require that ids be unique across all pages (not just in one page, I prefix with the page name, an underscore, and the numerical id that lets me access records in a database.

Instead of binding to a class or the ul control,  use 'on' to bind to the li of the parent list:

```
    $('#sortable').on('dblclick', 'li'  function() {
        aval = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/g); // only want the numbers...
        id = aval[0];
        name = $(this).text(); // in case you need these for a post...
        li = $(this); // so we can remove it from the list after the 'this' object changes inside the ajax call...
        // make an ajax call to the server
        var jqxhr = $.post( "somepage.php", {name: name, id: id},
            function(data) {
            li.remove();
            $("#sortable").listview("refresh");
    },'json').fail(function() { alert("error"); });
    return false;   // preventDefault doesn't seem to work as well...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be looking for the index of the elements with event

```
$('#sortable').on('click', '.itemDelete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target.parentElement).parent()[0].remove();
});
```